# Irritating - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, codesign

I've been trying from last 2 days,tried every solution available online,but all of them failed..

**The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.**

*The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.
(0xE8008016).*

I'm fed up guyz..i've to deploy my App on Ipad(ver3.2). please note that i dun't want to distribute it,so i think i dun need any entitlements.plist files.

Secondly, i've tried deleting all the profiles from my xcode as well as device, download the new provision profile and then tried,still getting the same error.

i've even tried deploying an empty project on Ipad,but still getting the error.

its making me insane.. :@, please help me out, I've to complete my project... :((

Comment: no its not...m trying to install the certificates again

Comment: i'm trying to build for Development

Comment: I posted an answet that worked for me here, check it to see if it works for you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333034/im-still-getting-the-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all the provisioning profile from system as well device, also delete from the download folder delete the development certificate from the key chain. Start again from the scratch. I had also faced the same problem. May be this can help